# PHP, Is creating a class for templates to much?

Tags: php, class

I am new to using classes heavily, and was wondering if going so far as to create a class specifically for templates was going to far. Here is a simplified version of my class template. Yes, I know I the use of `unset` is not necessary, but I like it there so don't give me any grief for it.

```
class template{
    private $templateString = "";
    private $templatePlaceholderStrings = array();
    private $templatePlaceholderValueStrings = array();

    function fillTemplateString($string){
        $this->templateString = $string;
        unset($string);
    }

    function fillTemplatePlaceholderStrings($array){
        $this->templatePlaceholderStrings = $array;
        unset($array);
    }

    function filltemplatePlaceholderValueStrings($array){
        $this->templatePlaceholderValueStrings = $arrray;
        unset($array);
    }

    function buildTemplate(){
        return preg_replace($this->templatePlaceholderStrings,
                    $this->templatePlaceholderValueStrings,
                    $this->templateString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a comment on style, you have the word template in every function... if you are calling a function on a template object, you don't really need to have that... e.g. `$template->buildTemplate()` why not just `$template->build()`?

Comment: What's so special about templates that you wonder if a `template` class is going too far? By the same argument, every single class you wrote might be going too far.

Comment: Agreed with @Jacob. Also why not to make `fillPlaceholder($name_arr, $value_arr)`?

Comment: This may be more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You have an error in `filltemplatePlaceholderValueStrings`, `$arrray` > `$array`...

Comment: First of, I agree with Jakob above (+1). Secondly using OOP allows for certain features, such as morphing classes, or make classes use certain OOP features.

Comment: @Jacob - Template really isn't needed. I should probably remove it. This was created in haste and I did not put much thought to my naming conventions. Also, I didn't know there was about codereview.stackexchange.com thanks for the link.

Comment: @Emmerman - The reason the placeholder string and value fill functions are separate is that they are not defined at the same time. The string is defined on `__construct` of another class and the `build()` of that same class is where the values are defined.

Comment: @webarto - would it be better to initially set it as empty and then store the array in it, or to parse the array parameter and assign each value into the already declared array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the rule of thumb I'd suggest to anyone who is unsure about how much OOP they should use: **use classes and objects wherever they make your life easier.**

In your case, I guess it will allow you to incrementally add variables/placeholders to your templates and it will centralize template handling so that you don't have to go around and search/replace code all over your files whenever you'll want to change things, so I guess it's a pretty good idea.

Edit: I misread your class originally, you should probably have something like this, if you want to be able to add placeholders from different part of your script rather than in one big call

```
function addPlaceholder($placeholder, $value){
    $this->templatePlaceholderStrings[] = $placeholder;
    $this->templatePlaceholderValueStrings[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: "incrementally add variables/placeholders" where did you see that bit? I think most of the people who posted answer here didn't bother to look at the actual code. They're just talking on general concepts.

Comment: I misread the class when I first parsed it, I've already edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A class for handling your templates is actually a good design choice. Usually you'll have too little classes, not too many, so don't worry too much about that :)

Comment: Uhm.. yeah... Have fun avoiding OOP in favor of trying to gain performance.

Comment: I am having fun doing that as a matter of fact. But that's not the case here. The thing is you need to use common sense sometimes and not an "OOP... gooood..." zombie attitude.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using flat files so the designer can open them in Dreamweaver, he will get scared if he opens phpMyAdmin to edit template. RegEx is not necessary.
There are many good template classes out there, take a look at them, and then write your own.

Class

```
class Template{

    public function v($v = "", $value = ""){
        $this->$v = $value;
    }

    public function render($templates){
        $templates = explode(",", $templates);
        foreach($templates as $template){
            include("html.$template.php");
        }
    }

}
```

Script (index.php)

```
include("class.template.php");

$template = new Template;

$template->v("title", "Hello World");

$template->render("header,index,footer");
```

HTML (html.header.php)...

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Webarto" />

    <title><?=$this->title?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: So what do you want to say here?

Comment: He should be using flat files for templates.

Comment: then write it in your answer to make it more effective

Comment: @Shakti Singh, there I've said it ;) based on my experience working as a back end developer.

Comment: @webarto - So say I have a class for a fill in the blank question (the blanks being text inputs) I should have php files for: the input, the question, and the form they are attached to. Not to mention, for each other question type and question part?

Comment: I don't quite understand but if you are talking about FORM elements, than yes, it is advisable to have separate form templates, eg for registration page (header,menu,registration_form,footer). That way you can use same template for create/update purposes.

Comment: @webarto - You're thinking of using template on a larger scale then I am. You are wanting to the form be a template, but I am wanting each input, select box, textarea, etc. to be a template. Essentially, you are wanting me to have a different php file for each input, select, textarea, ect.?

Answer (score 0):

All your class does is call a built-in function (but in 4 steps instead of 1!). There's no point in having that much overhead for a simple function call. You're not offering any additional functionality with your new API, you're just making it harder to do a string replace.

A clarification: If you intend to do something more with your patterns, then by all means, make a class for it. But as long as PHP's build in functions do the job, there's no point in complicating your life.

If you like acronyms, here's one: [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (not the band).

Comment: I respectfully disagree: the class encapsulates three individual string variables. This is already a reason to use it.

Comment: @Jon 1 string and 2 arrays. And those variables are the parameters to preg_replace. I really find it pointless to create a class for this.